# How to specify RecordTypeID using upsert in Account

Tags: account, soap

I need to specify a RecordTypeId in Upsert SOAP call for Account Object. I have tried following.

```
    <urn:upsert xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <urn:externalIDFieldName>External_ID_vod__c</urn:externalIDFieldName>
        <urn:sObjects xsi:type="sf:Account">
            <External_ID_vod__c>IT21_1100072988</External_ID_vod__c>
            <RecordTypeId>Test1</RecordTypeId>
```

However I get the following error.

```
        <errors>
           <fields>RecordTypeId</fields>
           <message>Record Type ID: id value of incorrect type: Test1</message>
           <statusCode>MALFORMED_ID</statusCode>
        </errors>
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to specify this. Any link to official documentation for this field is also fine.

Thanks in advance,
Vikas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is as follows.

```
            <RecordType xsi:type="sf:RecordType">
                <Name>Test1</Name>
            </RecordType>
```

Where RecordType comes from datamodel - relationshipName: RecordType

Answer (score 1):

Instead of name, you must provide **ID** of the record Type **not** its name. It looks like this:

```
<urn:upsert xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <urn:externalIDFieldName>External_ID_vod__c</urn:externalIDFieldName>
        <urn:sObjects xsi:type="sf:Account">
            <External_ID_vod__c>IT21_1100072988</External_ID_vod__c>
            <RecordTypeId>01240000000QKE5</RecordTypeId>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwani. Yes that works. But I was after something like this - 
    `<RecordTypeId xsi:type="RecordType">
     <Name>Test1</Name>
    </RecordTypeId>`

Comment: Sure will do, if I dont find a way to update using Name instead of Code.

Comment: In my scenario, I need to do this using Name instead of code.